# Wordpress always displays :| as an emoji

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site where we display song-lyrics. When there is a repetition we note the repedet part with "|:" at the start and ":|" at the end. Now the later is always replaced with  by wordpress. Can someone tell me how I can disable that replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from Kinsta:

https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-emojis-wordpress/#disable-emojis-code

Add it to your **functions.php**

```
/**
 * Disable the emoji's
 */
function disable_emojis()
{
    remove_action('wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7);
    remove_action('admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script');
    remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles');
    remove_action('admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles');
    remove_filter('the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji');
    remove_filter('comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji');
    remove_filter('wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email');
    add_filter('tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojis_tinymce');
    add_filter('wp_resource_hints', 'disable_emojis_remove_dns_prefetch', 10, 2);
}
add_action('init', 'disable_emojis');

/**
 * Filter function used to remove the tinymce emoji plugin.
 * 
 * @param array $plugins 
 * @return array Difference betwen the two arrays
 */
function disable_emojis_tinymce($plugins)
{
    if (is_array($plugins)) {
        return array_diff($plugins, array('wpemoji'));
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}

/**
 * Remove emoji CDN hostname from DNS prefetching hints.
 *
 * @param array $urls URLs to print for resource hints.
 * @param string $relation_type The relation type the URLs are printed for.
 * @return array Difference betwen the two arrays.
 */
function disable_emojis_remove_dns_prefetch($urls, $relation_type)
{
    if ('dns-prefetch' == $relation_type) {
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/formatting.php */
        $emoji_svg_url = apply_filters('emoji_svg_url', 'https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2/svg/');

        $urls = array_diff($urls, array($emoji_svg_url));
    }

    return $urls;
}
```